# yii Ajax call not going to correct action

Tags: ajax, yii2

I have the following link to make my ajax call in yii2:

```php
echo Html::a('Load more','ajaxShowMoreProducts', [
    'onclick'=>"console.log('Load more');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: 'ajaxShowMoreProducts',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('suc');
            }
        });return false;",
]);
```

Then I have an action in my SiteController:

```php
/**
 * @return string|\yii\web\Response
 */
public function actionAjaxShowMoreProducts() {
    var_dump('in');die;
    $params = [];

    $productModel = new Product();
    $params['products'] = $productModel->getAll();

    $this->renderPartial('partialProductItem', $params);
}
```

However when I click the link,the correct controller action does not seem to be called. Its still calling site/index. Any ideas what I have to do to get this working? Have i forgotten some sort of annotation or maybe I have to define my new action somewhere?

When I look in the console, it looks correct:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/site/ajaxShowMoreProducts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In yii2 you should use the proper notation for action url  (in url calling si not used the camelNotation but the words are separated by `-` (minus)

```
  echo Html::a('Load more','ajax-show-more-products', [
```

and in ajax url too

```
 url: 'ajax-show-more-products',
```

or try using Url Helper

```
use yii\helpers\Url;


 ....

        echo Html::a('Load more', Url::to(['/site/ajax-show-more-products']),  [
        'onclick'=>"console.log('Load more');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: '" . Url::to(['/site/ajax-show-more-products']) . "',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('suc');
                }
            });return false;",
    ]);
```

Comment: I have tried that but it still goes to index even though the url is: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/site/ajax-show-more-products

Comment: Ah thats done the trick! Thanks. Guess the clean urls dont work. This did work: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=site%2Fajax-show-more-products